# Layout is not loading in Custom module of Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

My config.xml file:  config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>    
       <modules>
    <Tutorial_Product>
        <version>1.6.2.0.4</version>
    </Tutorial_Product>
</modules>
 <global>
     <blocks>
         <product>
              <class>Tutorial_Product_Block</class>
         </product>
      </blocks>
    </global>
 <frontend>
    <routers>
      <product>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Tutorial_Product</module>
             <frontName>product</frontName>
          </args>
       </product>
   </routers>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <product>
                 <file>product.xml</file>
            </product>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

My controller file: IndexController.php

```
 <?php

      class Tutorial_Product_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->renderLayout(); 
    }
```

}

My block file: Monblock.php

```
            <?php 
        class Tutorial_Product_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
      {
        public function methodblock()
       {
        return ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
       }
     }
   ?>
```

I have created the folder for layout file in the following path:
app/design/frontend/product/default/layout/product.xml

```
          <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
      <reference name="content">
      </reference>
     </default>
  <product_index_index>  
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="product/monblock"  name="product_monblock" template="product/afficher.phtml" />
       </reference>
     </product_index_index>
      </layout>
```

I have created the folder for view file in the following path:
app/design/frontend/product/default/template/product/afficher.phtml

```
   <?php
           echo $this->methodblock();  
     ?>
```

My layout is not loading.. I am new to magento, so i am not able to identify the mistake..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In module `config.xml` `<global>` tag is added in `<frontend>` tag.

```
<global>
 <blocks>
     <product>
          <class>Tutorial_Product_Block</class>
     </product>
  </blocks>
</global>
```

Please add this outside of `<frontend>` tag.

**Updated Answer:**

1. Global Configuration File: app\etc\modules\Tutorial_Product.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Tutorial_Product>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Tutorial_Product>
  </modules>
</config>`

2. Module Configuration File: app\code\local\Tutorial\Product\etc\config.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

       <modules>
            <Tutorial_Product>
                <version>1.6.2.0.4</version>
        </Tutorial_Product>
    </modules>
     <global>
         <blocks>
             <product>
                  <class>Tutorial_Product_Block</class>
             </product>
          </blocks>
    </global>
     <frontend>
        <routers>
          <product>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Tutorial_Product</module>
                 <frontName>product</frontName>
              </args>
           </product>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <product>
                     <file>product.xml</file>
                </product>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>`

3. Block Class : app\code\local\Tutorial\Product\Block\Monblock.php

`class Tutorial_Product_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function methodblock() {
      return 'informations about my block !!' ;
    }
}`

I have used remaining code from your post and it worked for me perfectly

Comment: I have changed what you specified, I got the following error now:   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'about' (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/magento_source/app/code/local/Tutorial/Product/Block/Monblock.php on line 6

Comment: But it is not working for me.. I have done the same that you have specified.

Comment: Is your request coming in corntroller action ?

Comment: No it is not coming.. Do i need to do anything in admin side?

Comment: Copy my complete code in your config xml file. I think `</config>` tag is missing at last

Comment: No config tag is there.. I have given... problem is there somewhere else i think.

Comment: No admin setting you need to do .. just check your code carefully may be there is some typo mistake. because same code is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your follow-up mistake:
The string ‘informations about my block !!’ does not seem to be in proper apostrophes ('').